# How to run a function based on the URL?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a class to some elements on my page based on the current URL of the page.

This is the code I tried to use:

```
function loreslash() {
if (window.location.href == "https://teruko-124d7b.webflow.io/") {
    function(){ 
        $('#slashloreleft').addClass('active');
    }
}};
```

Then on onload

```
window.onload = loreslash;
```

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong but it's not working correctly. If anyone could give me an example of how to properly to do this I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do anything:

```
if (window.location.href == "https://teruko-124d7b.webflow.io/") {
  function(){ 
    $('#slashloreleft').addClass('active');
  }
}
```

Even when the `if` condition is `true`, all that code does is define an anonymous function that is never executed.

If you want to execute that one line of code, just execute that one line of code:

```
if (window.location.href == "https://teruko-124d7b.webflow.io/") {
  $('#slashloreleft').addClass('active');
}
```